# Criterion for weakly lower semicontinuity in problems of calculus of variations

Tags: optimization, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let’s say I have to minimize a certain integral functional $F(u)= \int_{\Omega} L(x,u,\nabla u)$ with $\Omega$ regular and $u$ in a certain Sobolev space (don’t really care to be precise, I just want a general idea). To prove there exists a minimum, let’s say I want to use the direct method. No problems for compactness, but when I want the lower semicontinuity for weakly convergent sequences (the derivatives, typically) I am kinda lost. I know the norm is weakly lower semicontinuous, but is there a simple general criterion to have weakly lower semicontinuity, in general?

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly a convexity assumption on the lagrangian $L$ is sufficient to get the w.l.s.c. I think it's in Evans's book? Or maybe Jost's.

Comment: Convexity and strong semicontinuity is enough, indeed. The problem is that in dimensions greater than 1 you usually only have $L^p$ convergence for the sequence. I mean, if I had uniform convergence then a a continuous Lagrangian would work. But with $L^p$ convergence, how do I have strong lower semicontinuity given strong $L^p$ convergence?